# Math Functions that cannot be reversed?

Tags: math, encryption, operators, hash

I am curious about developing my own **Simple** Hashing mechanism.

I would like to know some math functions that are irreversible.

I know that raised to function and modulus are some functions that are irreversible in the sense that the reverse procedure gives two answers.

> e.g.:- square root(4) = 2 or -2

I need a function that is not reversible because, even if anyone cracked my cipher, they should not be able to produce a decrypter, that can easily decrypt the passwords in my hashing.

Using this functions I can make my hashing more secure.

**It would be helpful if someone could give more such functions with explanations.**

Comment: What you're talking about isn't salting - it's the hash part. Salting is just about adding some extra information - which is typically stored with the hash - to avoid the same plain text from hashing to the same value.

Comment: You have the terminology confusing you. Salt is a number of arbitary  (usually random) bytes added to a Hash for more security. Hashing is a one way math function. Salting a hash just adds extra protection and avoids the use of bruteforces, rainbow tables and [collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistant) that might produce the same hash.

Comment: Also see this great link: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hashing_Java#Why_add_salt_.3F

Comment: Sorry sir i need some mathematical functions that are just irreversible like square-roots and modulus ! ! I am interested in devoloping a one-way hash mechanism!

Comment: I believe windows uses such one-way hash for storing the administrator passwords. If not then please correct me!

Comment: What is the goal of your function? In particular does it need to be fit for password hashing? We can only help you if you state your goals/requirements clearly.

Comment: @CodesInChao  I am interested in creating a oneway encryption that is irreversible in the sense that if i encrypt a password ,no one can create a decrypter and use it to find the password in plain text. If they want to crack the hashes they need to individually enter all the passwordss until it mathches the hashes..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Squaring in R is irreversible in the sense that it loses information. But that's not at all what hash functions are about.

Cryptographic hash functions have two main properties:

1. It's hard to find two inputs with the same output, called a *collision*
2. It's hard to find an input matching a given output, called a *pre-image*

Squaring on R has neither of these properties:

1. Finding a *collision* is trivial. Given `x` just calculate `-x`, both of which square to `x*x`.
2. Finding a *pre-image* is easy. Calculate the square-root. There are efficient algorithms for this. (Ignoring the problem that you can't output the infinite sequence of digits if the result is irrational)

Unfortunately there are no "simple" functions with these properties.

Related questions:

- [Why are hash functions one way? If I know the algorithm, why can't I calculate the input from it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/why-are-hash-functions-one-way-if-i-know-the-algorithm-why-cant-i-calculate-t)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I just dont need the normal hashing method !i am developing a cypher code for each charecter and want to encrypte them into a one way hashing..

Comment: Then describe what you're trying to do. For all we know, you want the constant function. `(x) => c`

Comment: For eg:- suppose the cipher code for A = -12 and if my function was squaring that function it results in 144. And if some one want to decode 144 to the normal value ie -12   then it would be difficult for them..

Answer (score 2):

Modulo is irreversible. Absolute value is irreversible. Rounding is irreversible.

Answer (score 1):

1. Power of 0.
2. Imaginary numbers are good as a computer can only pass the equation if it already knows what to do with it.
3. Rounding numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Salting "functions" should be reversible. The point of a salt is just to add extra (hard to guess) data to the value you want to hash. This way, attackers have a much harder time reverse engineering hashes with their own guesses.

One common solution is to just prepend/append the salt to the text you're going to hash.

For example, if your hidden value was "password" and your salt was a random number between 0 and 255, the thing actually stored in your database might be md5(123password), 123. So it doesn't really make sense for the salt operation to be irreversible, as it's already hashed, which is, *kind of*, irreversible.